# Excel : Corresponding value of minimum value(multiple minimum values)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to fetch values based on unique values from Column A
i.e. for L1 & L2

ex : for L1,
I need to find minimum date in column C i.e. D1 and
then its corresponding value in column D i.e. A
& for L2,
I need to find minimum date in column C i.e. D1 and
then its corresponding value in column D in this case i.e. C

I tried with

```
INDEX(D:D, MATCH(IF(MIN(A:A="L1", C:C, "")), C:C, FALSE)
```

its giving me results of the first match.....
As L2's min date is D1, its taking the first occurrence of D1 and give me result as "A" but I need "C""

[image]

Comment: it is easier to help you, if you provide your sample data as inline table, e.g. using [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)

Comment: Are your dates really dates?  Or are they tokens as you show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below assumes your dates are actually dates, and not tokens as you show in your screenshot. *(If they are tokens, you will need to split the text and number so you can obtain an accurate minimum date)*

There are a number of ways to do this.

- If you have Microsoft 365:

  - `INDEX, SORT, FILTER`.
  - `INDEX, MATCH, MINIFS`
  - *as suggested by @JvDV*: `INDEX, SORTBY`

For example, with your data table above made into a **Table** named `Status`:

```
H2: =UNIQUE(Status[State])
I2: =INDEX(SORT(FILTER(Status,Status[State]=H2),3),1,4)
```

or, as suggested by @JvDv below:

```
I2: =INDEX(SORTBY(Status[Status],Status[State]=H2,-1,Status[Date],),1)
```

and fill down

Or, if you only want to enter a single formula in H2, you can try:

```
H2: =BYROW(UNIQUE(Status[State]),LAMBDA(arr,INDEX(SORT(FILTER(Status,Status[State]=arr),3),1,4)))
```

and the results will `SPILL` down

[image]

If you have an earlier version of Excel, you can list the `State` in Column H, generating that list in a variety of ways, and use the following **array formula** in I2 (and fill down as needed):

```
I2: =INDEX(Status[Status],MATCH(MIN(IF(Status[State]=H2,Status[Date],"")),IF(Status[State]=H2,Status[Date],""),0))
```

Depending on your version of Excel, you may need to enter/confirm this **array formula**, by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>. If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula seen in the formula bar.

Comment: Hm, strange. I derived on that suggestion based on my attempt [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bma1T.png)

Comment: @JvdV Never mind, you have `I2` in your formula and it should be `H2`

Comment: @JvdV nice catch on using the header as start value of REDUCE. Something to remember.